# c# Label is "empty"/is a hole in the form

Tags: c#, forms

I have 2 windows. The main form and the Loading form. In the main form you send a request which will be executed. Because this takes some time, I made the Loading-form with a progress bar so that the user knows the program is working.

What I want to: The Loading-form should open itself when the process ist started and close itself when it's finished.
At the moment I have code that looks something like this:

```
    Loading.Show();
    Loading.MakeAStep();    //used for progressing the progress bar

    //program is working

    //finishes
    Loading.Visible = false;
    Loading.ResetProgress();    //Sets the value of the progress bar to 0
```

My problem is: The window with the progress bar opens, but there is also a label which shows "please wait". When the form opens, the progress bar works perfectly, but the label is just a hole (it really is you can look through it). When I use instead of visible = false     form.Close, it works just fine with the label but I get an error when I try to start a progress in the same session.
What I want/need: Either a solution to the hole-problem, or an effective way to open and close a form several times during one session.

Comment: you can try loading.hide(), i hope loading is the name of the form object.

Comment: @HiteshMistry Thanks for the suggestion it works like invisible = false but it couldn't solve my problem :/

Comment: That's entirely by design, the UI thread of your program can do only one thing at a time.  ProgressBar is a bit special since it forces a paint when you update its Value property.   Label does not do that, you can help by adding Loading.Update().  The only right way to do this is to move the code into a worker thread so you don't hang your UI.  Consider BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author)*.

The answer is in the comments: The UI blocks and I needed to Update the form with `Loading.Update();` I put that between Show and MakeAStep.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by others, the problem is that you run your long running process in the UI thread. To avoid this, you should improve how the loading form receives the task and works on it:

The loading form should get the thing to run as a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) (maybe by a method `Run(Task task)`. After getting this task the loading form can attach another action to it, what shall happen when the task is finished by using [`.ContinueWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) and simply closes itself when it reaches that point. After that it will [`Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682.aspx) the task and call [`ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) on itself.